# Java setter does not change the value of an integer

Tags: java, private, getter, setter

**EDIT**: added MovementDataStorage data = new MovementDataStorage(); to main class as pointed out in comments to clarify.

I have 3 classes, all in the same package.
Code snippet from main method in class Main:

```
ActionsMovement move = new ActionsMovement();
MovementDataStorage data = new MovementDataStorage();

move.goForward();
System.out.println(data.getLocationNorth()); //this would show 0, intended result is 1
```

My ActionsMovement class has the following snippet:

```
MovementDataStorage data = new MovementDataStorage();

public void goForward()
{
      if (data.getDirection().equals("North")) {
            data.setLocationNorth(data.getLocationNorth() + 1);
    }
}
```

And finally, my MovementDataStorage has the following code snippet:

```
private int locationNorth;
private String direction = "North";

public int getLocationNorth() {
        return locationNorth;
    }

    public void setLocationNorth(int locationNorth) {
        this.locationNorth = locationNorth;
    }

    public String getDirection() {
        return direction;
    }

    public void setDirection(String direction) {
        this.direction = direction;
    }
```

when `move.goForward();` runs, the value of `int locationNorth` does not increase - I tried checking the value both from main method and from inside of `goForward` method.

If I manually change `int locationNorth` value, I can see the change. If I do it through `move.goForward();` it doesn't seem to change.

If in my `main` method I add:

`data.setLocationNorth(data.getLocationNorth()+1);`

`System.out.println(data.getLocationNorth());`

The value of `int locationNorth` does become what I would want it.

**Code runs and compiles with no errors/exceptions**

Comment: This is where a debugger comes in handy...

Comment: Short advice: locationNorth is not initialized, in your class.

Comment: @Andrea which is why it starts with default value 0

Comment: @Kleronomas perhaps the value is not equal to "North"

Answer (score 3):

The problem is you have two `MovementDataStorage`, one in `Main` class which you print and another one in `ActionsMovement` which you set its value.

One solution will be to use `MovementDataStorage` from `ActionsMovement`.

```
class Main {
    ActionsMovement move = new ActionsMovement();
    move.goForward();
    System.out.println(move.getData().getLocationNorth());
}

class ActionsMovement {

    public MovementDataStorage getData() {
        return this.data;
    }
}
```

If you need `MovementDataStorage` in main you can create an instance and send it as parameter

```
class Main {
    MovementDataStorage data = new MovementDataStorage();
    ActionsMovement move = new ActionsMovement(data);

    move.goForward();
    System.out.println(move.getData().getLocationNorth());
}

class ActionsMovement {

    MovementDataStorage data;

    public ActionsMovement(MovementDataStorage data) {
        this.data = data;
    }

    public ActionsMovement() {
        this.data = new MovementDataStorage();
    }

    public MovementDataStorage getData() {
        return this.data;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The expression

```
if (data.getDirection().equals("North"))
```

is obviously not evaluating to true. My guess would be it is either not initialized correctly or has a different value.

Answer (score 0):

So your `ActionsMovement` already contains a `MovementDataStorage` so there's no need to recreate that object in your main method.

So in your `ActionsMovement` class you should maybe have a function which retrieves the `MovementDataStorage` like so:

```
public getMovementDataStorage() {
    return this.data;
}
```

Then from your main you could do something like this:

```
ActionsMovement move = new ActionsMovement();

move.goForward();
System.out.println(data.getMovementDataStorage().getLocationNorth());
```